# Chatception - quickly chat in different rooms from a single page (v0.3)

Tags: script, chat

### TL;DR

> [I got fed up with having 11 chat tabs open all the time and made a userscript to fix it.](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3420695#3420695)

### Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

### Description

A tiny widget that allows you to quickly chat in different Stack Exchange chatrooms from a single page.

- Hover over any of the chatrooms shown on the right side of the page to pop up the small widget.
- It will show a history of the last few messages from that chatroom (with full formatting, including oneboxes), the user who sent them, and a timestamp.
- Type in the text field at the top to quickly send a message to that chatroom.
- Hover over the username of any message shown in the widget to reply to, delete, or edit it.
- The timestamp of any message shown also acts as a permalink.
- The amount of unread messages will show up in `[brackets]` next to the room names in the sidebar, and a total will be displayed in brackets in the title of the page (right next to the number in `(parentheses)` that shows the amount of unread messages in the current room, which stays intact).

### Download / Code

Userscript can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/KeyboardFire/stackexchange-chatception) (this post is just the README.md copy/pasted).

Comment: Direct link: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KeyboardFire/stackexchange-chatception/master/stackexchange-chatception.user.js